# Is it possible to use external indicator to activate display attribute in display file?

Tags: ibm-midrange, indicator

I am currently amending an existing RPG program. The aim is to set on an indicator so that this indicator will activate the display attribute ND in a display file to hide a field. The problem is that all the general purpose indicators IN01~IN99 have been used up, and I cannot reuse any of them without disturbing the existing program flow. Is it possible to use external indicator U1~U8 instead? If not possible is there any other alternative? Or am I just screwed?

Comment: That's pretty amazing.  How big is this program (how many lines of code, how many open files)?  It's hard for me to imagine writing anything that uses that many indicators, even in RPG III.  I am very confident there are indicators being used that don't need to be.  (Not saying that cleaning up the indicator usage is the quickest or best solution; just marveling at the previous programmer(s) who created this monstrosity.)

Comment: The program is about 4000 lines and it references more than 20 files.  But the real problem is that my company uses ERRMSGID keyword in DDS to display message in display files. There are around 90 messages to be displayed in this program. And I can tell you this is not the only program in my company which uses all 99 indicators. Of course the program can be rewritten to prevent unnecessary indicator usage but the effort involved is too much and is not recommended by my boss. What a shame...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a program to system field instead of an indicator.  http://wiki.midrange.com/index.php/Program_To_System_Fields

Another possibility is to externalise all the display file indicators via the DDS keyword INDARA  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzakc%2Frzakcmstdfindar.htm

Comment: Is external indicator not a good choice here? Or it does not work here at all?

Comment: The only indicators that DDS allows are 01-99.

Comment: For the INDARA solution, do you mean to remove a response indicator from the buffer and use it to activate the new display attribute?

Comment: No.  INDARA sets aside a separate 99 byte buffer for all the indicators on the record format.  If you use INDARA you will need to change all the places that the existing code uses an indicator for the DSPF and change it to use the INDARA array.  Using the Program to System field is easier if you only need to add a few more indicators.  Here's an old example: http://archive.midrange.com/rpg400-l/200402/msg00197.html

Answer (score 2):

Check the usage of each indicator 01-99, to determine if you might be able to free them up for use in your dislay file.

IF any of them are only used to control the program flow, and not directly involved in display files, print files, I-specs, or O-specs, THEN you may substitute its use with an indicator-type variable.  Declare a variable with an internal data type of N (position 40 of your D-spec) as a character indicator-format field. Use this variable in place of an indicator that is used only for program flow control.

If there are no such indicators, then you should probably use one of the methods Buck recommended.

An old-style alternative, you could save the entire indicator array *IN to a holding area, re-use some of the I/O indicators temporarily, then plop the holding area back onto the indicator array.  You might have multiple 99-indicator structures that you move to *IN, or load from *IN, at the appropriate time.  You could have one such structure for each record format which you would move to *IN right before I/O on that record format, and load back after the I/O.  This gives you an almost infinite number of indicators in your program, although still limited to 99 per display format.

Comment: Hopefully, the old program is not full of hanging indicators with crazy and/or combinations.