# How to disable a function key in a display file without using indicator to deactivate its command function?

Tags: ibm-midrange

Suppose in a display file DDS CF20 has been specifies to make F20 available. Now I want to disable this function when certain condition is met in a RPG program. As this program has already used up all the general purpose indicators In01-IN99, using an indicator to deactivate CF20 keyword in the display file is not an option. Is there any other alternative to achieve this?

Comment: Are some of the indicators internal (to the program) only?  If so, and your version of RPG supports it, consider using general logical (`N`) type variables.  Or have you actually managed to use up all 99 indicators in your display/printer file?  If so, your program is _probably_ too large, and should be split up.  I can't recall for certain, but you _may_ be able to use P-fields to turn keys on/off (but I've never worked with them) - I do know you can do some things, like change colors, protected status of a field, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user presses F20 and the RPG program has decided this is not allowed, notify the user and disallow the F20 action inside the program.  In other words, don't do anything at all to the display file, do all of the work inside the RPG program.

Comment: Does it mean that it is not possible to deactivate F20 in the display file without indicator?

Comment: Right.  Only an indicator can condition whether F20 is available or not.

Comment: Use another technique to free up one of your other indicators, then you can use it to control F20.  Buck and I both recently answered a question on those methods. [ I gotta learn how to put the link in ;-) ]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649945/is-it-possible-to-use-external-indicator-to-activate-display-attribute-in-displa/11650818

Comment: Oh it was his question anyway.  :o)
Thanks Buck